# How can one solve polynomial equations with constant terms that have a high number of factors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quartics

Today I was given this question on a test:

> $x^4 - 20x^3 - 20x^2 + 1500x - 9000 = 0$. Find the value(s) for $x$.

I know how to solve these types of equations. I must record the positive and negative integer factors of the y-intercept or constant term, use guess-and-check to find one factor, and then use synthetic division to factor the equation.

However, there are a very high number of factors for 9000. I know that Descarte's Rule of Signs can help determine whether to consider the positive/negative factors, but even then the number is very high. I guessed and checked as much as I could before realizing I would not be able to solve the question in time.

Is there a quicker way of finding the first x-intercept or zero?

Comment: Your title specifies y-intercept, the body of your post ask for solutions of the equation.  Please edit to clarify

Comment: Thanks, changed it.

Comment: Try letting $x=10u$ and solving for $u$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That seems to help, except you end up with an equation that doesn't have any rational roots. Thus it cannot be solved using synthetic division and factoring.

Comment: Actually, by graphing, I just now realized that the original equation does not have any rational roots. We were not permitted graphing calculators on the test, so now I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: best guess is that there are some incorrect coefficients in your polynomial.

Comment: What does "incorrect" mean in this context?

Comment: @FouadSaffar  if you copied them perfectly here, it is still possible that the polynomial in the exam was not really the one they had hoped; the usual trick  of writing a quartic as $(x^2 + ax + b )^2 - c(dx+e)^2$  (with $c>0$ )  does not seem to work here either. That is about the only alternative I know that can be done by hand. Hmmm, maybe use $x=10 u$ and try again

Comment: No, the 10u method definitely does not work algebraically. Perhaps they wanted me to graph it by hand?

Comment: Something interesting happens if it is $-50x^2$ rather than $-20x^2$ and $x\to10u+5$. You get the square of a quadratic. In order for this to be a fair question, the student would be expected to try a substitution of the type $x\to au+b$.

Comment: Also, the student would have to have a graphing calculator.

Comment: Setting aside the possibility/likelihood that the problem statement became garbled at some point, I would consider a substitution $x := t+C$.  This shift can narrow the location of positive real roots qua Descartes Rule of Signs.  This preserves the degree of the polynomial and (if $C$ is an integer) the integrality of coefficients.  Note that a monic polynomial with integer coefficients cannot have real roots that are rational unless those roots are actually integers.

Answer (score 2):

try $$  x^4 - 20 x^3  - 20 x^2 + 1200 x - 16000  $$

with the suggested $x = 10 t,$   then divide the result by $2000,$ we get
$$  5 t^4 - 10 t^3 - t^2 + 6 t -8$$
To write as a difference of squares, we multiply back by 5,
$$  25 t^4 - 50 t^3 - 5t^2 + 30 t -40$$

Next I wrote this as
$$  (5 t^2 - 5 t + a)^2 - ( bt +c )^2  $$  and tried, to begin, with integer $(a,b,c)$   and that works.  It turned out that one could arrange $b=0$  for this problem.

If that had not worked, I would have hoped for $x$  values of the form $\sqrt{v \pm \sqrt w}, $    by allowing an extra coefficient $d > 0$  in
$$  (5 t^2 - 5 t + a)^2 - d( bt +c )^2  $$

Comment: what is the meaning of this?

Comment: @okzoomer  I suspect  the polynomial  was given incorrectly in the  test. My version can be dealt with by hand

Comment: I didn't know that on MSE we could be like "OP's question can't be solved, therefore let's randomly change 2 numbers to make it solvable".

Answer (score 2):

While not a solution to OP's question as stated, if we suppose that the coefficient of $x^2$ is in error, and that a coefficient of $-50$ rather than $-20$ was intended, then the resulting polynomial graph is symmetric about the vertical line $x=5$.

In general it can be shown with a bit of algebraic manipulation that a quartic $P(x)=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$ is symmetric with respect to the vertical line
$x=h$ if and only if $h=-\frac{B}{4A}$ while $B(B^2-4AC)+8A^2D=0$.

These conditions are met for

$$x^4 - 20x^3 - 50x^2 + 1500x - 9000 = 0$$

Letting $x=t+5$ we find that

$$ P(t+5)=t^4-200t^2-4625 $$

whose roots are easily found.

Comment: you have a point. The repeated $-20$  coefficient was a bit jarring to the eye. I went immediately to some integer roots, Yours is more likely...Before the $x=t+5,$ I imagine there is a good expression as $(x^2 - 10x + a)^2 - b (cx+d)^2 $  where $b > 0,$  that is something they seem to teach for contests.

Comment: on second thought, one ought to depress the cubic term first, if the outcome still has a linear term try difference of squares